# Fix mesh topology so subdivision doesn't create artifacts

Tags: normals, subdivision-surface, topology

So I'm new to blender and 3d modeling, I modeled this and am reasonably happy with the result, however when I add a subdivision modifier, the edge of the ear on the back the front look bad, there are also artifacts with the surface's smoothness a bit where the other circled points are.

I'm assuming this is a problem with my mesh topology however I'm unsure of the best way to fix it.

[image: Mesh Front]
[image: Mesh Back]
[image: Mesh artifacts top]
[image: Mesh artifacts ear]

[image]

Edit: I was able to fix one of the issues by reworking the mesh a bit (though I'd still like to know if this was the only way, or if it could have been fixed in a better way)
[image: Partial fix]

Edit 2: I've redone the ear, I think the topology works a lot better now (no squished diamond shaped quads, and it seems to have improved the normals when subdivision is applied

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a .blend file for us to look at?

Comment: Sure, what's the recommended way to add a the .blend file to the post?

Comment: Upload it on https://blend-exchange.com/ there you find instructions what to do, you'll then get some HTML text you can edit into your question.

Comment: uploaded, thanks for the instructions on how to do so.

Comment: I suggest you tighten up your topology, wrapping neat edge loops around the entire back of your mask, like you did on the front, and an edge loop around the ear, like you did with the snout. This will squash your artefacts.